# What is the sedimentation coefficient of Mycoplasma?

Tags: biophysics, centrifugation, mycoplasma

I have attempted to find the sedimentation coefficient of a number of bacterial species, namely *E. coli* and a number of *Mycoplasma* species, but they seemed to be rather elusive in the literature.

If such values cannot be easily found, is there a reason sedimentation coefficients of whole cells are not widely reported, but sedimentation coefficients of proteins are? Mentions of "70S ribosome" and "26S proteasome" are common, but I have never seen any mention of "kilosvedberg" or "megasvedberg" appearing in the literature, and I presume the sedimentation rate of whole cells would fall somewhere in this region.

Comment: Alternatively, use regular centrifugation speed to pellete down bacteria for calculation of sedmentation coefficient. Generally its 5000 RPM for 6 min at 4 degree (convert this into terminal velocity). Just find out radius of rotor and angular velocity of your centrifuge then calculate $s = \frac{V}{r*w^2}$